# The condition for integral domain R to be P.I.D.

Tags: ring-theory

If $a_{i}$ are nonzero element in R such that $a_{i+1}$ divides $a_{i}$ for all i, then there is a positive integer N s.t $a_{n}$ is a unit times $a_{N}$ for any $n$ larger than N.

I wonder that given condition imply "every ideal of R is finitely generated"

How to check this?

Comment: What if $R$ is the ring of polynomials in infinitely many variables with coefficients in some field. Any nonzero element of $R$ involves only finitely many of the variables, so I think any divisibility chain stabilizes the way you want, but not every ideal is finitely generated.

Comment: Yes I agree you, but the original state ment is that (1) any two nonzero a,b in R have g.c.d which is wrriten in the form ar+sb for some r,s in R (2) the condition stated above. Then 1,2 implies R to be P.I.D

Comment: I have thought condition 1 is equivalent to finitely generated ideal is principal. So i guess that (2) might be equivalent to every ideal is finitely generated.

Comment: I don't understand the comments. Are you saying the question you asked is not the question you wanted to ask? If that's the case, you should edit your question so it asks what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention the *ascending chain condition for principal ideals*.

This condition, together with the condition that ideals generated by irreducible elements are  prime, characterises *unique factorisation domains* (`UFD`s).

Now not all UFDs are noetherian. E.g. the ring of polynomials in a countable number of indeterminates over a field $K$, $K[X_n]_{n\in\mathbf N}$, while being a UFD, is not noetherian.